# saving figure using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython

I have multiple plots each displayed in each tab(each tab is a page in wx.Notebook). I have attached the code snippet used to plot the figure in each tab. Everything is fine till I try to save a figure using the option in navigation toolbar. When I try to save a figure, the figure in that plot gets messed up and the tab looks like the image attached. How can I fix this issue? 
Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

```
    self.fig = plt.figure(figsize=(hor_pix, ver_pix), dpi=self.dpi)
    self.canvas = FigCanvas(self, -1, self.fig)
    self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
    self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas)
    line_ico = wx.Image('line.bmp', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
    self.line_button = self.toolbar.AddSimpleTool(wx.ID_ANY, line_ico, "Line", "Extract using line Marker")
    paste_ico = wx.Image('paste2.bmp', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
    self.paste_button = self.toolbar.AddSimpleTool(wx.ID_ANY, paste_ico, "Paste gates", "Copy gates from other plots.")
    self.toolbar.Realize()
    self.SetSizer(self.vbox)
    self.vbox.Fit(self)

    self.axes.hist(datam3,bins,color='b',ec='b',fc='b')
    self.canvas.draw()
    self.Refresh()
    self.Update()
```

[image: image of tab after clicking on save button]

Comment: try setting the dpi of your saved figure and displayed figure to be the same.  Can you simplify your example code at all (strip out anything which is not relevant and plot synthetic data)?  You will get better answers if you make it easier for people to understand your question.

Comment: How can I set the dpi of saved figure? Is that not done by Navigationtoolbar module of matplotlib? I have edited the code which in brief adds 2 tools(line, paste) to navigation tool bar and plots a histogram.